# Changing existing jhipster project from JWT authentication to OAuth2 Authentication

Tags: jhipster

I had implemented a project using jhipster . Initially i was using JWT authentication. We built our project using this. But now the requirement changed and we want to use OAuth2 Authentication. I build a new jhipster project and choose OAuth2 Authentication and tried to compare it with our existing project but the changes are huge. Can anyone suggest me how can i solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The changes should not be huge unless you compare code generated by 2 different versions of JHipster.

Make sure you use same version of JHipster as when you generated your project and change authenticationType in the `.yo-rc.json` file in your project folder, run `jhipster` in your existing project folder, compare changes with git.

Comment: In newer versions (e.g. 6.5), just type 'jhipster'.